# Graphs (Nodes and Edges)

Tags: haskell, graph-theory

I am using HASKELL for graph games. I am willing to get a suitable method for reach ability from a node to a particular node in the graph apart from using bfs or trees etc.

---

As I asked for code in haskell for reach ability from one node to a particular node, it is necessary to tell you that I am totally new to haskell. I have been reading the tutorials and simple examples, but when it come to implementation then I am lost. My graph is a directed graph, and say I want to check whether I can reach from node v to node w in graph.

Answer (score 8):

From [Data.Graph](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Graph.html):

```
reachable :: Graph -> Vertex -> [Vertex]
```

To search the Haskell API and libraries:

- http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/
- http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html

Answer (score 2):

There are several [All pair shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_pairs_shortest_path) algorithms in hand. For small graphs, wikipedia says:

> [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm) is an
> elegant, quickly implementable O(n3)
> algorithm (Assumes absence of
> negatively-weighed cycles).

**EDIT:** Are you looking for a ready-made Haskell code?

Comment: Yes if possible.
What I want is, as I used graph as list of nodes and list of edges, so how v a node is reachable from w another node in the graph. The code of such reach ability

Answer (score 2):

Try representing your graph as a matrix where a 1 represents an edge.

E.g.:

```
 Node/Node  A  B  C  D
          A  0  0  1  1
          B  0  0  1  1
          C  0  0  1  0
          D  1  0  1  0
```

For directed graphs the order of the matrix indices matters, for undirected graphs they don't.  The above being a directed graph where there is an edge from D->C but not from C->D.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your question is, in the context of Haskell.

- Are you asking for readymade implementations of the required algorithms + data structures?
- Looking for libraries for graphs in Haskell?

Either way, check http://hackage.haskell.org  for graph-related packages:

1. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl
2. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz
3. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Graphalyze
4. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GraphSCC
5. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgal